# Center an element in the middle of nav

Tags: html, css, centering

How can I make my nav at the top, be centered based on the position of the image, rather than the block of the entire nav?

The reason why I was thinking of this is because if someone had a long name, the nav wouldn't even look centered. I was wondering about making a relative position but I am not sure if that would work, or by using floats or what not.

```css
.profileinfo {
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
.profileinfo:nth-child(2) img {
  align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.profileinfo:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
.profileinfo:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
.profileinfo:last-child,
.profileinfo:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li class="profileinfo">Ashley Siwiec</li>
  <li class="profileinfo">
    <a href="/accounts/profile/">
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/60">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="profileinfo">C: 175</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have constant dimension of the middle `img`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set absolute position for first and last `<li>`s, so that they will be out of the normal content flow. Then only center the middle `<li>`. For the alignment you can use `transform` for it.

That will ensure the middle image to be centered horizontally always. And 2 other items on each side, vertically centered.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.container li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.container li:nth-child(2) img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container li:first-child,
.container li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.container li:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%);
}

.container li:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container li a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>Ashley Siwiec</li>
  <li><a href="/accounts/profile/"><img src="//dummyimage.com/60"></a></li>
  <li>C: 175</li>
</ul>

<ul class="container">
  <li>Ashleeeeey Siwieeeeec</li>
  <li><a href="/accounts/profile/"><img src="//dummyimage.com/60"></a></li>
  <li>C: 175</li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqzL0mwq/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.profileinfo:nth-child(2) {
  background: #111;
}

.profileinfo:nth-child(2) img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.profileinfo:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.profileinfo:last-child {

  border-left: 1px solid white;

}
.profileinfo:last-child, .profileinfo:first-child {
  margin-top:20px;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li class="profileinfo">Ashlefdsgsdfgfdsgdfsgy Siwiec</li>
  <li class="profileinfo">
    <a href="/accounts/profile/">
      <img src="/images/profilepics/github-512.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="profileinfo">C: 175</li>
</ul>
```

try using flexbox. Here is a helpful site explaining it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes I also wrote up a quick snippet.